# Chrome won't let me visit non-SSL website

Tags: google-chrome, browser, ssl

I have a website I'm developing that is on a small server on my network. I have the DNS set up for it as "example.dev". I have been able to access it in Chrome without fail up until today.

When I type in "example.dev" into the address bar, the site comes up as unavailable and Chrome changes the address bar to `https://example.dev`. So I remove the "s" to it's just `http://example.dev` and try again, but again it changes to `https`.

I do not have any sort of SSL set up on this server. The site has always been available only as `http`. This just started happening today.

I can type in `http://example.dev` and visit the site just fine in Firefox and other browsers.

Per other suggestions, I have tried visiting this page:

chrome://net-internals/#hsts

And deleted the domain security policies for `example.dev` but this did not make a difference.